# Multiple data-id values in HTML5

Tags: jquery, html

It is posible to have multiples data-id values ?
I have the below li ( acts as a filter button in a jQuery script
And i want to hook several data-id to the same li
F ex: i have Breakfast, Breakfast Buffet, Bed And Breakfast.
How can i hook them to the below li ? Is there a certain sepparator for this?

```
<li data-id="Breakfast" data-filter="board">
<a href="#">Breakfast<small class="total-bb"></small></a>
</li>
```

If it helps here is the jQuery that i use with the above li

```
$(".filters li").on("click", function () {
        id = $(this).data("id");
        filter = $(this).data("filter");
        $("#hotel-list .col-sm-6").show() && id == "all" || $('#hotel-list .col-sm-6:not([data-'+filter+'="'+id+'"])').hide();
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add it as an array, and jQuery will read it as an array

```
<li data-id='["Bed", "Breakfast"]' data-filter="board"></li>
```

and

```
var ids = $(this).data("id");
```

and then do something like

```
$(".filters li").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var ids    = $(this).data("id"),
        filter = $(this).data("filter");

    $("#hotel-list .col-sm-6").hide();
    $('#hotel-list .col-sm-6").filter(function() {

        return ids.indexOf( $(this).data(filter) ) !== 0;

    });
});
```